# JSplitPane is painting over JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jsplitpane, jmenu

when I create JSplitPane and JMenu:

```
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane();
pane.setLeftComponent(new SidePanel()); // extends JPanel
pane.setRightComponent(new LibraryPanel()); // extends JPanel

add(pane);

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
// Creating menuBar
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

After resizing JSplitPane, JMenu's in JMenuBar component are drawing under JPanel elements. How to fix?

Comment: Which layout manager do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was my typo :) And instead correct "JLabel" there was "Label". Sorry.
Check your code :) Cause, I already wrote my own Split Panel :)

Thanks for help!